# \e in cmd.exe interpreted in PATH

Tags: cmd.exe

This wasted about 2 hours of time this afternoon, and I'm not even sure why. I was hoping someone could shed some light on it. Was trying to a command from cmd.exe

The command entered:

```
cmd.exe /C TYPE "%CMDER_ROOT%\scripts\elpfile.txt" && pause && exit
```

Errors out every time, saying "The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect."

```
"C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\cmd.exe" /C TYPE "C:\Program Files\cmder\scripts←lpfile.txt" && pause && exit
```

Obviously, the \e is being interpreted. But I can find no reference as to this being something that should occur. My fix was just to rename the file, (it wasn't actually named "elpfile" I just did that to demonstrate).

Answer (score 0):

#### Errors out every time, saying "The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect."

The syntax of your command is wrong.

> ```
> CMD [charset] [options] [/C Command]
> ```
>
> - Command - The command, program or batch script to be run.
>              This can even be several commands separated with '&' 
>              (**the whole should also be surrounded by "quotes"**)

You need to surround the whole Command string with quotes <kbd>"</kbd>

Use the following:

```
cmd.exe /C "TYPE "%CMDER_ROOT%\scripts\elpfile.txt" && pause && exit"
```

---

#### Syntax

> ```
>   CMD [charset] [options]
>   CMD [charset] [options] [/C Command] 
>   CMD [charset] [options] [/K Command]
> ```
>
> **Options**
>
> - `/C`     - Run Command and then terminate
> - `/K`    - Run Command and then return to the CMD prompt.
>           This is useful for testing, to examine variables
> - Command - The command, program or batch script to be run.
>              This can even be several commands separated with '&' 
>              (the whole should also be surrounded by "quotes")

Source [cmd](http://ss64.com/nt/cmd.html)

---

#### Further Reading

- [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/) - An excellent reference for all things Windows cmd line related.
- [cmd](http://ss64.com/nt/cmd.html) - Start a new CMD shell and (optionally) run a command/executable program.

Comment: I had tried that previously. The exact same behavior occurs. --> "C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\cmd.exe" /C "TYPE "C:\Program Files\cmder\scripts←lpfile.txt" && pause && exit"

Comment: @variable That strange character `←` is only displayed in my text editor if I encode the text as UCS2 Big Endian. What code page are you using? Is this line being typed at the command line or in a batch file?

Comment: I've typed it in at three locations; straight into run, via Windows Key+R and then also into CMDER window running cmd.exe itself, and then again in PowerShell.

Comment: Weird. Then I'm out of ideas ... :/